# Space-Complexity of Van Eck's Sequence

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

What is the space-complexity of Van Eck's sequence?

https://oeis.org/A181391

Input: $x$ (number in binary representation with $n$ bits)

Output: $x$th number in Van Eck's sequence

Length of input: $n$

The naive algortithm would generate one entry of the sequence after the other and store all previous entries. Storing $2^n$ numbers of up to $n$ bits would need $n2^n$ bits. Maybe you are lucky and smaller numbers appear so often more than large numbers, that you only need constant space for each number. This would reduce space-complexity to $O(2^n)$. But can you do better than that?